# Evaluation of curly braces in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

I’ve noticed that we can use curly braces to make some of the commands much shorter as it is evaluated into list of arguments.

Input:

```
echo a{,b,c}
```

Output:

```
a ab ac
```

How do I force the same behaviour when the arguments are passed from the file?

Input:

```
cat file.txt | xargs echo
```

Output:

```
a{,b,c}
```

Expected output - same as in the previous example.

Comment: You can't do this without enabling parsing stages that will let contents in your file run arbitrary script contents (ie. `$(rm -rf ~)`). It's best not done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `{}` expansion is a `bash` / `zsh` feature, as such then you need to explicitly run it thru any of these shells, in your case would be (using `-I<STRING>` to let xargs replace it in the string before running it):

```
cat file.txt |xargs -I@ bash -c 'echo @'
```

Answer (score -1):

1. `xargs` calls the `echo` as found in the $PATH, not the shell's builtin echo.
2. check the [list of bash expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions): brace expansion happens first, so it won't get a chance to expand in that pipeline.

You'll have to do something like

```
while read -r line; do eval echo "$line"; done < file.txt
```

which exposes you to all kinds of nasty attacks if someone puts something malicious in that file.

Answer (score -1):

Other than asking why would you want to do this... I offer the following:

add the string to a file:

```
echo 'a{,b,c}' > /tmp/foo
```

put the string in a variable:

```
export thing=`cat /tmp/foo`
```

`eval` the string:

```
eval $thing
```

If you had a bunch of these in a file then run the file through a loop and eval the loop value:

```
echo 'a{,b,c}' >> /tmp/foo
echo 'a{,b,c}' >> /tmp/foo
echo 'a{,b,c}' >> /tmp/foo

for i in `cat /tmp/foo`; do eval echo $i; done
```

Comment: In `export thing=$(cat /tmp/foo)`, the exit status of `export` overrides that of `cat`, so you don't know if the command failed. Better to `thing=$(</tmp/foo); export thing` as two separate commands.

Comment: And btw, better to just put your whole block in a redirection like `{ echo one; echo two; echo three; } >/tmp/foo` so you only open the output file once -- when you `echo one >/tmp/foo; echo two >>/tmp/foo; echo three >>/tmp/foo`, you're opening and closing the output file three separate times.

Comment: And better to `eval "$thing"` than `eval $thing`; when you do the latter, you're string-splitting and glob-expanding your variable contents *before* you send the list of strings created by that process into `eval` (for it to reassemble into a single string to send to she shell's parser).

Comment: To give you a concrete example, try `thing=' echo " * " '` and then compare `eval $thing` and `eval "$thing"`; you'll see they have two different results. (But don't do the former if you don't trust there not to be maliciously-named files in your current directory! If someone had run `touch $'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\''` in the directory you're in, that former `eval` is a quick route to a bad day).